# How to click button available in dynamic web table using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am new to Selenium, I have gone through the website tutorial  https://www.guru99.com/handling-dynamic-selenium-webdriver.html to learn how to get the row count & column count for the web table.

But in our website testing we need to do a few more advanced operations.
The web table is similar to demo website http://demo.guru99.com/test/web-table-element.php.

**Questions:**

1. My table row value will be dynamic, for example first time loading ("BEML Ltd.  A   253.1   327.4   + 3.7") row number will be 6th place. Maybe next time the row will display on 10th place, due to few more rows being added.
2. Now how to find the particular value from the third column ("Previous close RS")  for example "253.1"?
3. Based on the match value I have to click the corresponding button available in the first column (Example  "BEML Ltd" - web site link). The demo website has only one link in fist column. But my test website has three buttons: Hold, Close, Open.

I have tried using the below code, but I am not able click and navigate the to corresponding screen.

```
   try:
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'td')))
            table= self.driver.find_element(By.ID, 'TableGrid')
            trs = table.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')
            for tr in trs:
                tds = tr.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
                for td in tds:
                    match_obj = re.search('searching Text', td.text)
                    print(match_obj)
                    if match_obj and match_obj.group(1) == '0':
                        success_button = tr.find_element_by_css_selector('button.btn-success')
                        print(success_button.get_attribute('type'))
                        success_button.click()
        except :
              pass
```

OK.simply I am asking how to match particular value in any columns in the dynamic growing web table ( the row index is not fixed) and click the button available in the particular row of the first column?

Comment: I couldn't understand the output you wanted. Can you say the output you want?

Comment: Can you give a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'td')))
    table= self.driver.find_element(By.ID, 'TableGrid')
    trs = table.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')
    row_count = 0
    matched_row_count = 0
    for tr in trs:
        tds = tr.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
        time.sleep(2)
        for i, td in enumerate(tds):
            # This for loop will iterate single row value. Here i is index value 
            if i == 1 and td.text == 'required matching column value':
               #print("Matched {}: {}".format(i, td.text))
               matched_row_count = row_count
               print("matched_row_count :",matched_row_count)
        row_count = row_count+1
        # will print all the column name  #//*[@id="TableGrid"]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]/a[3]
            # tr[4] -row [td1]-column a[3]-button
except :
      print("could not found the column details")

element = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tr:nth-child("+matched_row_count+")"+" "+".btn-info")
actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
element = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body")
actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,  "tr:nth-child("+matched_row_count+")"+" "+".btn-info").click()
```